# set() method doesn't work in JavaFX properties

Tags: java, javafx, properties, actionlistener, scenebuilder

Recently I created a `JavaFX` application to demonstrate `properties`.

1. First I created a class called 'Numbers'. Here is the code.

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Numbers {

    private DoubleProperty number;

    public final double getNumber() {
        if (number != null)
            return number.get();
        return 0;
    }

    public final void setNumber(double number) {
        this.getDoubleProperty().set(number);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty getDoubleProperty(){
        if(number == null)
            return new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        return number;
    }
}
```

2. Then, in my `controller class`, I created an object for 'Numbers' class.

```
final Numbers num1 = new Numbers();
```

The rest of the code is like following.

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    final Numbers num1 = new Numbers();

    @FXML
    private Label lblValue;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        num1.setNumber(0.5d);

        num1.getDoubleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                lblValue.setText(Double.toString(num1.getNumber()));
            }
        });

    }

    public void btnPlusClicked(ActionEvent event){
        num1.setNumber(num1.getNumber() + 1);
    }
```

But, text of the `Label` 'lblValue' doesn't change when the relevant button is clicked. I did some edits and found that the problem is not with `Action Listener`. I think the problem is with the method `btnPlusClicked(ActionEvent event)` or the `set()` method of the `property`. Please someone help me to clarify this scenario.

P.S.:

- I followed a YouTube tutorial and he created this exact application. He made those methods and instances `final` and I don't know why. I just tried to imitate his piece of code. Someone please explain the significance of `final` keyword here.
- I can confirm that I successfully configured method `btnPlusClicked(ActionEvent event)` via Scene Builder also.

Comment: You never set any value to your field `DoubleProperty number` in the `Numbers` class. So `number` will always be `null` and your `getNumber()` method will always take the path to `return 0;`. If i had to guess, i would recomment trying to change the line `return new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);` to `number = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);` to actually set your field to something and see if it works then.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS That works. Thank you. Actually I've made a mistake in typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you're watching is using the "lazy pattern" for JavaFX properties. That is, the property object itself is not created until either written to or queried directly. But there's a mistake in the implementation. I don't know if the tutorial made a mistake or if you simply made a mistake when copying the code, but the property getter should look like:

```java
public final DoubleProperty numberProperty() {
  if (number == null) {
    // this constructor sets the initial value to 0.0
    number = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "number");
  }
  return number;
}
```

Note two differences between the above code and your code:

1. The above sets the `number` field, then returns the value of said field.

   You are currently returning a *new* `SimpleDoubleProperty` every time and never storing it. That means you can't observe it for changes because you change a different instance whenever you set the property.
2. The name of the method is `numberProperty`.

   That follows naming conventions for JavaFX properties, which is: If you have a property named `foo` then the getter should be named `getFoo()`, the setter (if writable) should be named `setFoo(...)`, and the property getter should be named `fooProperty()`. Note the setter should have only one parameter whose type matches the value type stored in the property.
3. *Bonus:* I set the "bean" and "name" of the `SimpleDoubleProperty`.

   This is not strictly necessary to make your code work, but is the "proper" thing to do.

Comment: Actually, I have made a mistake while copying the code. The tutorial did it correctly.... Your answer _"2. The name of the method is `numberProperty`. That follows naming conventions..."_ was very helpful because previously I didn't concern much about the naming conventions. Please explain further _"3. Bonus: I set the "bean" and "name" of the `SimpleDoubleProperty`. This is not strictly necessary to make your code work, but is the "proper" thing to do."_.

Comment: What are the parameters passed in `number = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "number");`? How does it differ from my code? What is the significance of using `final` keyword in these methods?

Comment: The `this` argument is the "bean", the object to which the property belongs (if any). The `"number"` argument is the name of the property. The [`ReadOnlyProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyProperty.html) interface defines methods to get these values. Passing those arguments is different from your code because you don't pass them (not sure how to elaborate there). The use of `final` prevents you, or anyone else, from overriding the methods in a subclass.